# Wrap text within a asp:Button

Tags: asp.net, html, button

I was using a LinkButton and it had like lot of text in it which made it quite long. This was fine as the LinkButton wrapped the text onto the next line when it ran out of room.

I then changed this to a standard asp:Button and the problem is the text doesn't wrap the button just becomes as long as the text. This is a problem because it forces the container it is within to be longer than I intended.

Is there a way to make the text of the button wrap?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do that by setting a width and the CSS property `white-space: normal`:

This goes in your `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrap { white-space: normal; width: 100px; }
</style>
```

And your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="some really breally long text that I want to wrap" CssClass="wrap" />
```

Comment: Thanks wsanville, just what I needed. Brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="some really breally long &#010; text that I want to wrap"  />
```

This question was helpful and wanted to point out if we want to break the text in a specific spot we could also by adding the  
 within the text value.

I also marked wsanville answer as useful.

Comment: I have discovered, quite to my consternation, that these characters are ignored by IE10. *sadface*

Comment: In FF 50 it is also ignored

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a width on the asp:button (width=100) and that should force the text to wrap.

Comment: No, that just truncates the text

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternate solutions in this post that may be helpful:

[ASP:Button Text Word Wrap](http://forums.asp.net/t/845028.aspx/1)