# Wrapping Text in a Button Text Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have been trying to wrap text in the Text Field of the asp button control.

Suppose I have a long file name which is kept in the text field of text box. Now if I do not set the `width` of the button it can grow to `200px`. But I want the `width` to be `100 px` and the text to be wrapped in the text field or I can set the text to be multi-line.

Comment: I tried posting a photo as an example to this ques, but could not since i am a new user and do not have enough reputation points to post it.

Comment: [Reference1](http://forums.asp.net/t/845028.aspx/1)

[Reference2](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/26817/asp-button-text-to-wrap-to-second-line/)

Comment: you should use `word-wrap` or [`white-space:pre-wrap`](http://jsbin.com/oyuyag/2/edit) property of css check this [link](http://jsbin.com/oyuyag/1/)

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268354/wrap-text-within-a-aspbutton

Answer (score 1):

Replace space with `&#13;&#10;` Try following code

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button&#13;&#10;Button&#13;&#10;Button&#13;&#10;Button" Width="100px" Height="200px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width of the button to 100px, and increase the height of the button.

If required, you can also decrease the padding of the button, so that the text fits-in.

**Update:**

What you can do then is a bit tricky, but works for me.
Make a div styled like a button, put "width:100px;height:auto" in CSS. And make the real button display:none in CSS.

Write a click event for the div, and click the real button manually from there.

```
$("#divButton").click(function () {
    $("#btnReal").click();
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: if i do so, it will fix the button attributes and if i get longer text than the previous one again the text will be truncated.

Comment: @Rahul2788 : Updated my answer accordingly. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

One link from comment leads to this solution:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitBatch" runat="server" Text="Submit&#10Batch" Font-Bold="true" />
```

But this doesn't work in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

**c#:(in the code behind on cs page)**

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Text1");
sb.AppendLine("Text2");
BtnID.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Add some explanations behind the rationale of why you are suggesting this code.  This will discourage copying and pasting without understanding.

Comment: @rayryeng: One can create a string of texts programmatically and then show the same on the button..There is no automated wrap of texts on button on the .aspx page. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to use CSS to achieve this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="This is some really long text that I want inside the button" CssClass="wrap" />
```

And now the CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .wrap
    {
    white-space:normal;
    }
```

Comment: @VMAtm It sure does for me. Are you saying that `white-space:normal;` doesnt work in chrome?

Comment: I've copied your code to the test page, opened it in Chrome, and it doesn't work for me. Version 23.0.1271.97 m.