# How I can set button text on multiple lines in C# from aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a button in my project whose text I am setting through aspx.cs page.
Here is code of button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEmailRequestSummary" runat="server" OnClick="btnEmailRequestSummary_OnClick" />
```

Here is code from aspx.cs page

```
if (//condition)
{
    btnEmailRequestSummary.Text = "Generate & Email - Request Summary";
}
else
{
    btnEmailRequestSummary.Text = "Generate Request Summary";
}
```

I need a 'Summary' word to be appear on next line. I tried using `<br />`, `\n`, and also ASCII values for `<br />` and `\n` but no luck.

Comment: try this `btnEmailRequestSummary.Text = "Generate & Email - Request "+ Environment.NewLine +"Summary";`

Comment: @Lifewithsun I tried using `Environment.NewLine` but no change it appear in single line.

Comment: Anurag  then you have to try as per Ankit suggested by using css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : As pointed in comment this solution might not work on some browsers, please use CSS to achieve this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268408/1531476)

declare this CSS class :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrap { white-space: normal; width: 100px; }
</style>
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
btnEmailRequestSummary.Attributes.Add("class", "wrap ")
```

This might work on some browsers,

```
btnEmailRequestSummary.Text = "Generate Request &#010; Summary";
```

[ampersandHash010;] character entity normally gives the new line in Button Text.
Refer this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) for more Character Entity References:

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it didn't work it show button text as Generate Request &#010; Summary.
The same happen when I used ASCII codes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this 
CSS:

```
white-space: pre;
width: 60px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

With the exact text for the button being:

```
string.Format("Generate & Email - Request {0} Summary", Environment.NewLine);
```

**NOTE**: the spaces before and after the `Environment.NewLine`