# Adding line break to message for asp-alert-message modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, nopcommerce

So I'd like to show a modal with 2 lines with a line break between them, here is the tag:

```
<nop-alert asp-alert-id="updateAddressAlert" asp-alert-message="@string.Concat("message1", "<br/>", "message2")" />
```

But I can't seem to be able to use make a line break, I tried the above, I also tried `string.Format` and:

```
var str = $"{msg} <br/> {msg}";

var str1 = msg + " <br/> " + msg;
```

Of course `\n` will also not work, it seems I'm missing something but I can't figure it out, and I've lost too much time with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: @Arshad, I did not, I'll do it right now.

Comment: @Arshad, it doesn't work, worth the try though

Comment: it seems some html and css issue. You can check by inspecting the element how it is rendering in the UI. It is hard to tell without replicating or seeing it.

Comment: @Arshad, this a nop commerce tag, I'll try to create a MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add style in your view

```
<style> 
[asp-alert-id="updateAddressAlert"]{ 
      white-space: pre; width: 60px; word-wrap: break-word;
} 
</style>
```

Then in the controller

```
var str = $"{msg1} {Environment.NewLine}{msg2}";
```

Based on this post [multiple lines in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452798/15142527).